# Workbench throws "503 Server Unavailable" error

Tags: workbench

Since a month ago we frequently see an "Application error" when launching actions (queries, anonymous apex, rest calls, etc) in Workbench.

The chrome debug console tells us there is a server side issue (HTTP 503 Server Unavailable).

Is this a Workbench or a Salesforce issue?
How can we escalate this further?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The workbench is an unsupported product. You cannot escalate the issue. We don't know when, or if, this bug will be fixed. You're welcome to try and diagnose the issue yourself (it is [open source](https://github.com/forceworkbench)) and submit a PR (I've done this before, it's not too hard), but there's no guarantee when it will be fixed.

You can spin up your own copy on a private Heroku stack, which is also not difficult (I spun up one on [Heroku](http://foxworkbench.herokuapp.com/login.php)). I've considered hosting my own copy, but unless I receive donations, I can't guarantee that I can keep my own instance running, scaling up Heroku is prohibitively expensive for someone with my income. You're free to try and use my copy for now, but I make no guarantees of availability.

If this continues indefinitely, I am considering building a brand-new Lightning-based app to fill this gap. If there's significant interest in such a product, I would consider doing so.

Comment: Just curious, have you seen the bug crop up on your instance?

Comment: @VictorLockwood I haven't tested it extensively, though i have not run into any 503 errors personally while using it. I'd be curious to know if anyone else has. I'm sure it would be possible to get some resource limiting errors, because this is only a Hobby instance for now, but I'd consider scaling it up if there was sufficient interest.